# Reference: Derivations on the $(2n+1)$-dimensional Heisenberg algebra

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

I am looking for a reference (either a book or a paper) which treats the $(2n+1)$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra $\mathfrak h_n$ (see [Wikipedia: Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Lie_algebra_2) for the definition). More particularly, I am looking for a reference in which the space $\mathrm{Der}(\mathfrak h_n)$ is determined.

This is of course not difficult to do by hand, but I would guess that this is fairly well-known, so I would rather just refer to some previous work than include the details of it in my own work.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Wonderful, thanks! (It's no rush, so you can look it up whenever you find the time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivations of the $(2n+1)$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie Algebra have been determined, for example, [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=2ahUKEwi07_Wv7-TlAhXGfFAKHZH0B9UQFjAJegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhal.archives-ouvertes.fr%2Fhal-01215682%2Fdocument&usg=AOvVaw38apXhFVKi4YEKSJs3dEXM) in Proposition $9$. The case $n=1$ has been computed at this site here:

[Examples of derivation of Lie algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489676/examples-of-derivation-of-lie-algebras)

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks